# Scripted Motion Paths (?) (XNA)

Tags: xna-4.0

Ok, so the title isn't the greatest because this is a lot more general.
Say I want to have the player be able to hit A and have their ship model roll to the right, and shift to the right of the screen, while the camera stays centered. Would I do that through programming (ie. set waypoints for the model and keep the camera focus still) or do it through animation ( so the ship model actually rolls and moves right, and just play those frames)(I actually don't know how to do this kind of 3D animation yet, haven't looked into it. Adding it to my To Do List)

This is a really vague question I know, I'll try and answer any questions.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2):

As always, it depends.

It depends mostly, on the scope of your project. I'm all for doing things clearly over correctly (if there is such a thing), so if this is a learning project, and you're not specifically interested in learning how to implement animations in your pipeline (which is an extremely complex thing by itself), then I'd say you should do this programmatically, and focus your efforts on solving a whole lot of problems that ensue in undertaking the development of a game.

Now, if this is a large project with budget, people and time, you will most likely need to implement this with animation, so your 3D designer can tweak it as she likes, regardless of what the code says. In more enterprisey terms, this is "separating logic from data".

More practically, you have the advantage that it is a ship model, which is most likely a rigid object without joints, so you can get away with modifying the ship transforms directly.

Remember, you want to *remove*, not *add* obstacles so you can get closer to completing your game every day.